# Spelling suggestions module in pure Python (for GAE)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, spell-checking, aspell

Could you recommend me a spelling suggestion library that can be used in Google App Engine (pure python).

Before moving to GAE we were using aspell-python.

**UPDATE**

What about some spelling API (e.g. google, yahoo, bing)?

Answer (score 0):

I would have a look to [whoosh for App Engine](https://github.com/tallstreet/Whoosh-AppEngine).
It offers a pure-python spell checker.